# Why this interface comes in Xubuntu when booting

Tags: boot, xubuntu

Recently my Xubuntu was caught by a problem, that whenever I shut down my laptop, it froze for 1-2 mins. I solved the problem by changing `DefaultTimeout` from 90s to 5s, as suggested by the Ask Ubuntu community.

But now a new problem is created. Whenever I boot my laptop, a message appears for 2-3 seconds:

[image: error message]

```
[    0. 156784] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_GPE. (72]
, AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20201113/dsuload2-326)
[    0.156809] ACPI Error: AE ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (202011
13/psob ject-220)
[    0.156821] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_S8.AMAC],
AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20201113/dswload2-326)
[    0.156828] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During mane lookup/catalog (29291113/psob ject-220)
/dev/nuncOn1p2: clean, 203608/1525920 files, 1672578/6163552 blocks
```

I want to know why this message appears. Is it an error of Xubuntu or something related to my hardware? Or should I change the `DefaultTimeout` back from 5s to 90s?